# Firestore query reads all the documents again (from database) when only one is modified even with persistence enabled

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Expected Behavior**: I assumed that when some field of a document is modified, query will only return that document and so it would be considered only 1 read. Say I query a collection with n documents, I would hope that it would be n reads for the initial state, and if a document is modified later only that document would be read again from database, resulting in n+1 reads in total.

**What I see** 
is n reads initially, and n reads later whenever one document is modified **regardless of Offline Persistence** being enalbed or not; resulting in 2n reads with all "**fromCache : false**" metadata.

```
  myCollection: 
         doc1 : 
              value: "some string"
         ...
         docn: 
             value: "some text"
```

later I change value for one document via console:

```
     myCollection: 
         doc1 : 
              value: "changed to other value"
         ...
         docn: 
             value: "some text"
```

But I get all n documents again in the snapshot of query. Regardless of the fact that I can observe changes using "s.docChanges", it seems that snapshot has all the n documents.

```
  const someCollectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection("collection/document/subdocl‌​lection"); 
  someCollectionRef.onSnapshot(s => {

      var d = [];
      s.forEach(doc => {

           d.push(doc.data()));

           //fromCache is always false even when one document is 
           //modified it seems that all documents are read from db again 
           console.log(`metadata is ` , doc.metadata);  
      }
      //d seems to have all my documents even when only 1 is modified

  });
```

**No difference with offline persistence enabled.** I tested the same example with offline persistence enabled and no difference! Modifying a document still causes all the documents to be read with "fromCache : false" metadata, i.e, they are read from database. The only time data is being read from cache is when a query is refreshed but documents are all identical.

Comment: If you're getting more results than expected, I'd look into that first before thinking about billing.

Comment: My example is the plain example from the documentation. I am not getting more results than expected, but when I modify one document , the query seem to be returning all the documents in the snapshot again which then I can use snapshot.docChanges to break it into "added,modified, removed" segments. So it seems even changing one document returns the whole set of results again. I thought it should return only the changed document! Hence my question about being charged for all documents again.

Comment: Please edit your question to illustrate exactly how you are changing the database, the result you expect, and the actual result.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added more info. Cheers

Comment: How do you define `someCollectionRef`?

Comment: I have a collection/document/subcollection structure and the reference is on the subcollection like this:  firebase.firestore().collection("collection/document/subdocllection")

Comment: My experience using the Anrdoid SDK and a test that attempts to duplicate your scenario is that when the listener is attached, the first query snapshot contains 3 documents and 3 docChanges (all Add).  When a document in the DB changes, the query snapshot contains 3 documents, and 1 docChange (Modified).  My guess is that the unmodified documents come from the client-side cache and you are not charged for them.  [This doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) describes a different scenario, but hints at use of local cache.

Comment: @BobSnyder, I logged the metadata and it doesn't seem anything is being read from Cache. Edited my question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: @MarcG: maybe try debugging the bytes over network to see if all the documents are being transferred or only the ones that changed. Please do post results, this is a good question

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this behavior and did some research: actually all is well!

When you are listening to a collection of N documents, you perform N reads for the initial state, then 1 read when a documents changes, as expected. This is described nicely in this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/3aoxOtMM2rc?t=147), and in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) for the billing aspect.

The trap is the fromCache metadata. When you receive an update for a document change, all the other unchanged documents have **fromCache: false, but they actually come from the cache**, as described by a Firebase dev in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590183/6016470)!

The fromCache metadata is true only in the scope of offline persistence, when the initial N reads were done from the local cache. When a document has received data from the server, it sets fromCache: false, and never goes back to fromCache: true. The naming is disturbing, but it seems to be working as expected.

And the code for testing:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.23.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
        <script>
            firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().then(() => {
                    const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection("/fruits");
                    collectionRef.onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: true}, snapshot => {
                    console.log("=================== snapshot received ===================");
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        console.log(`doc ${doc.id}, metadata:`, doc.metadata);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I modify a document using Firebase console, and in my browser's console, when the long polling request terminates, it shows that **a single document was transferred**:

```
15
[[14,["noop"]]]370
[[15,[{
  "documentChange": {
    "document": {
      "name": "projects/xxx/databases/(default)/documents/fruits/apricot",
      "fields": {
        "color": {
          "stringValue": "red"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2020-10-13T08:14:19.649748Z",
      "updateTime": "2020-10-13T14:16:09.991161Z"
    },
    "targetIds": [
      2
    ]
  }
}
]]]122
[[16,[{
  "targetChange": {
    "resumeToken": "CgkI+bft8+Cx7AI=",
    "readTime": "2020-10-13T14:16:09.991161Z"
  }
}
]]]15
[[17,["noop"]]]
```